# How to resequence after filtering for aggregation /Spring Integration/

Tags: filtering, integration, spring-integration, aggregation

I'm doing a project in Spring Integration and I have a big problem.
There are some filtering components in the flow and later in the flow I have an aggregation element.

The problem is that the filtering component does not support to "apply-sequence" property. It filters out some records without modifying the original sequence number however the number of messages are reduced. 
Later in the flow I need an aggregation which fails releasing elements since some messages are filtered out.

I don't want to use any special routing elements which have apply-sequence property.
Can you suggest me any common solution for this type of filtering problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you misunderstand the behaviour of the `filter` and `aggregator`.

I guees you have some `apply-sequence`-aware component upstream. So, all messages in that group accept several headers - `correlationId` - to group messages in the **default** `aggregator`; `sequenceNumber` - the `index` of the message; `sequenceSize` - the number of messages in the group.

`Filter` just checks messages for some condition and sends them to the `outpu-channel` or does `discard` logic. It doesn't modify messages. However even if we could do that, it doesn't sounds good anyway.

Assume we have just only two messages in the group. The first on is OK for filtering - we just send it to the `aggregator`. But the second is discarded, and, yes, it won't be sent to aggregator. And the last one never releases that group, because the `sequenceSize` isn't reached.

To overcome your requirement you need to have some custom `ReleaseStrategy` on the `aggregator` (by default it is `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`). For example to check some state in your system that all messages in the group have been sent independently of `true` or `false` result after `filter`. Or have some `fake` message for the same reason and check its availability in the group.

In this case you will need just take care about `correlationId` to group messages in the aggregator.

**UPDATE**

> What is the suggested release strategy for such a scenario? Would it be a good strategy to use timeout as release stretegy?

What I can say that sometimes it is really difficult to find good solution for some integration scenarios. The messaging is `stateless` by nature, so to correlate and group an undetermined number of messages may be a problem.

There is need to see requirements and environment.

For example when all your messages are processed in the single thread you can safely send some `fake` marker message in the end directly to the `aggregator` and check it from `ReleaseStrategy`. And it will work even when all your messages from the group may be discarded.

If you process those messages in parallel or they are received from different threads, you really won't be able to determine the order of messages and the time for each process.

In this case the `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` really can help. Of course, there will be need to find the good timeframe compromise according to the requirements to your system.

Comment: Thanks for your long explanation.

I know what is filtering and aggregation but I cannot write a release strategy for a group which let's say at the beginning has 10 records but some filters filter out some of them.

I don't know how many records fill be filtered out as the input can be a large set of various records. Nobody knows for how many records we should wait. Will there be 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 records at the end of filtering?
What is the suggested release strategy for such a scenario? 
Would it be a good strategy to use timeout as release stretegy?

Comment: Upated my answer. (Sorry, if there are english mistakes...)